# python3 manage.py runserver does not work without specifying the localhost

Tags: python-3.x, django, manage.py

Earlier when I executed,

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

It used to start the server at my localhost http://127.0.0.1:8000/

but somehow it isnt doing so now, when I type it in now and press enter, nothing happens and the cursor just goes to the next prompt.

However if I type in,

```
python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

It works correctly and starts the server.

What could be the issue? Is doing ctrl+C not stopping the already running server? How do I find out if I have any other servers still running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already running services in the background it would say that port 8000 is already in use. If for example you have started django with different port, for example:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:4000
```

and you need to check if the process is still running in the background type:

```
jobs
```

Check [this article][1] for more information. Note that if running:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

does not throw any errors, this is not related to background jobs.

[1]: https://study.com/academy/lesson/background-processes-in-linux-definition-manipulation.html#:~:text=In%20Linux%20terminology%20(and%20in,available%20to%20execute%20other%20commands.

Comment: Thanks I tried jobs but it didn't show anything, also for some reason now both commands with and without the 127.0.0.1:8000 do not start the local server.

Comment: You may need to check your processes if something is preventing it to start

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
netstat -nltp
```

to check used ports.

And close or kill it using

```
kill -9 PID
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this but there's no process running at port 8000, also for some reason now both commands with and without the 127.0.0.1:8000 do not start the local server.

Comment: Are you using python virtualenv or venv? Maybe it's on the environment.

Comment: using virtualenv @ron_olo